# Changing the width of Autocompleter

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, autocomplete, ace-editor

I've been using ace auto-completor, and I have got a case where the length of the words is much greater than the ace autocompleter's default width.

[image]

I've added some CSS to bring in the horizontal scroll to the auto-completion but the words in the bottom of the list are being cut. Has anyone faced a similar problem and made some fix to show long names?

Comment: Can you add some code also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the issue by getting the length of the longest string inside the autocompleter and then made a span to replicate the same string with same font size and font family so that I can determine the width of the string.

```
                $('body').append("<span id='longText'></span>");
                var longElement = $('body').find("#longText");

                longElement.text(longestValue); //longestValue containts the Long String
                var longeElementWidth = longElement.width();
                var autoCompleterWidth = $(".ace_autocomplete").width();

                if (longeElementWidth > autoCompleterWidth) {
                    var newAutoCompleteWidth = longeElementWidth + 15 + "px";

                    $(".ace_editor.ace_autocomplete").width(newAutoCompleteWidth);
                } else {
                    //Defaulting the width of the autocompleter to 350px
                    $(".ace_editor.ace_autocomplete").width("350px");
                }                        
                longElement.remove();
```